# How can I normalize two sets of probabilities?

Tags: probability

I have this model:

$$P(e) = K_w  P_w(e) + K_d P_d(e) + \text{some random term}$$

where

- $P(e)$ is the probability of picking edge $e$, "all things considered"
- $K_w$ and $K_d$ are constant parameters which can be used to tweak the algorithm
- $P_w(e)$ is the probability of picking edge $e$, with consideration to the weight
- $P_d(e)$ is the probability of picking edge $e$, with consideration to the distance
- $\text{some random term}$ is used to soften the algorithm in its tendency to favor too
    many high probability edges resulting in allowing the search process to get
    stuck in local minima.
    Rather than an added term, this can also be performed by a simple function
    which prevents the probability to be less than say $0.05$ or more than say
    $0.95$.  A fancier sigmoid function may also do the trick.

How can I normalize $P_w(e)$ and $P_d(e)$? ($P_w$ is a weight and $P_d$ a distance.) Is there an easy to understand formula?

Is this necessary at all? $P_d$ is normalized ($1/d$) and $P_w = (x-\text{edge weight})/x$ is also normalized. The sum is $1$. I want to add $P_w$ and $P_d$ so the sum is $2$ but shouldn't it be $1$? I'm confused.

Update: Per request I try to answer the question but I think the problem I need to solve is more a general problem. I'm not a math or probability expert. My math is very basic. I've asked the same question in the math forum to no avail and I think the discussion becomes a bit strange. I failed to explain my question. The formula is part from the wikipedia article about ant colony optimization. The other part I tried to add a second probability about weight. X is a constraint and a fixed value. With normalized I mean the probabilities when add together is 1. I already have a script to solve tsp and bin-packing. Now I want to put them together and solve the capacited vehicle routing problem. My idea was to use a ant colony optimization and add the two set of probabilities. I didn't know that to add two set of probabilities is possible.

Comment: I have a general answer in preparation, but some more details might help. 1. Where is this formula from ? Can you provide a link / source ? 2. What is x ? 3. What do you mean by "$P_d$ is normalized $1/d$" ? That $P_d$ is constant across all $e$s ?

Comment: @steffen: I think I solved my question myself. I have answered your question maybe you can find an error? I'm not very good at math.